# Reading CSV files for accuracy of data

Tags: r

what is the best way to read data in csv files for considering the accuracy of data .
for example if any variable have only integer values and one or two values in double so all values should show as it is in database.

so in order to keep the accuracy of data which is the best way to read any csv database.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for something like the `pointblank` package to confirm data matches your expectations? https://rich-iannone.github.io/pointblank/

Comment: We can set the `colClasses` and `numerals` with *read.table*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the `{readr}` package you can use the build in `guess_max` argument. e.g.:

```
readr::read_csv(file = "path/to/my.csv", guess_max = Inf)
```

The default for `guess_max` is 1000, but this way it should always identify your column as `double`